# How do you declare the type a property of an object in-place, without needing to declare the type of the entire object?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to type a property of an object *as you’re writing the object*? As opposed to defining a type/interface beforehand.

The only thing I can think of is `as` but that’s too lenient. Consider:

```
type Comment = Required<{
    author: string;
    message: string;
}>;

const myComment: Comment = {
    author: 'Steve',
    // Error! :) 'message' is missing
};

const myData = {
    myComment: {
        author: 'Steve',
        // No error. :(
    } as Comment,
};

const myData = {
    myComment: <Comment>{
        author: 'Steve',
        // No error. :(
    },
};
```

I want `myData.myComment` to throw the same error.

This is a trivial example, of course. But if I'm writing a big complex object it would be nice to be able to declare types for portions of it on-the-fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: `Comment` is a built-in type in [`lib.dom.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.5.4/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L3520-L3527). If you use that identifier with the `dom` library, you'll get this error:
>
> Duplicate identifier 'Comment'.(2300)

You can use an identity function to ensure that the input is assignable to the parameter type:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=37&ssc=77&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwlC8UDeAoKUCGBXYALA9gE4BcUAzsIQJYB2A5gNxpQC2EZZGdEpF19TAL5MUAegBU4qAEkAZlBD4sULGWh4qZADQKlUALIBVAMoAVKGEL4AblQAm63NG40I1AMZRQkTITpY2GmAvfCh3fBo+KgwaXSxCKGsMABssaHFRFFksGndgKgioeygAHlMAPgAKJNSeKFMASlJzVHRCCGB42Jq0oRQUcMjgmgCAIzcARgQiuxKRlnHCKoByJ2Tk-GWGhigJZnQDw6Pjo4A9c4vTlABBPwCIIKh8eW9oZaj6ZaKyKBp8YIwHCodBoGFGyXUoTAGEIGDYwDcTxe4De80WywAdJUAEwAZgALABWBooDL9USiKAAEQiy2CsiI3GCwFCZCwYDAyRAXicUBcbionlevn8gWAAEIBhEKL8xm5sdN7JVVhB1pttrtKa9nokUmkFfBDVAAERrDbG-qDGUsEBUjDADBTRCtVggGD4Fhi0j2EowKou9DYPBEUjLYwI6wQZZafaa1jsTjcUMACSo0eYggaOj2l1zefzFxudzFSK8KKgyyQmBwBBI5EotEYUEEX00v3+mCBILBEJCFhhcI6iJ1wuWMExzAAClZIIRQBW2BwuFHvqxNGRG0VYqOq0Ha7wGwJm19RjgoO0AI5YKjtOxbss+MeYnEE4lQMnCS3S4I2u0Og3IMwNrup6DzAN6sx+pUAbVsGdbLNcEIAB7poci6JnUyzJqqGyoc2WZxvgADWKCflKkT4BCGIbHQlS-vajoahSyCuiBXosXuIYVuGECRl8gjNuRZCURA1H4LR9H-kxlJVsBHrsbuNZcQhyHRvGS5JhW2FqvxglAA)

```ts
type C = {
  author: string;
  message: string;
};

/** If you use this, you MUST provide the generic type argument to constrian your value */
function id <T>(value: T): T {
  return value;
}

const number1 = id<number>('hello'); /*
                           ^^^^^^^
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.(2345)
*/

// Don't forget to supply the generic type argument!
const number2 = id('hello'); // typeof value2 === "hello"

const myData1 = {
  myComment: id<C>({
    author: 'Steve',
    // message: 'Hi',
  }), /*
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Argument of type '{ author: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'C'.
  Property 'message' is missing in type '{ author: string; }' but required in type 'C'.(2345) */
};

const myData2 = {
  myComment: id<C>({
    author: 'Alex',
    message: 'Hello',
  }), // ok
};

console.log(myData1); // { myComment: { author: 'Steve' } }
console.log(myData2); // { myComment: { author: 'Alex', message: 'Hello' } }
```

Alternatively, if you're simply trying to avoid typing, you can define the comment ahead of the object in which you want to include it, like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwlC8UDeAoKUCGBXYALA9gE4BcUAzsIQJYB2A5gNxpQC2EZZGdEpF19TAL5MUAGwjBWIGPhZsawUnESp02PEVIByAMrAIANwhaANMzYcuPKFoASVUymEoUAY3w0KUgCIZgGAEYEZCkZOQgFKGcUFmlZeUkVZnUCEhsAQXEAD0d0C05ubVsIUVF8R2j3T0lY338AJmCkUPiIyUqPMnxxADoyugAKWr9AgEoGKAB6SZDYsITSZpTNGz1DYxNWdgLrOwcoqLdO7og+-EHhhvGpmea51oVFzBxU7UyIHM38qyKSsq0DoIjp4TmcLnFwgprtMQss0lp3p8tpZCjZiqVylEgA)

```ts
type C = {
  author: string;
  message: string;
};

let myComment: C = {
  author: 'Steve',
  message: 'Hi',
};

const myData1 = { myComment };

myComment = {
  author: 'Alex',
  message: 'Hello',
};

const myData2 = { myComment };

console.log(myData1); // { myComment: { author: 'Steve', message: 'Hi' } }
console.log(myData2); // { myComment: { author: 'Alex', message: 'Hello' } }
console.log(myComment); // { author: 'Alex', message: 'Hello' }
```

Answer (score 2):

Would an anonymous/inline interface work? You still need it to precede the object but it's more concise than `interface`/`type`:

```js
const myData: { myComment: Comment } = {
  myComment: {
    author: 'Steve',
    // error
  },
};
```

Comment: I'd prefer to be able to do it alongside the property in question. Imagine this is a really big object. But yes, I suppose this is my best bet.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use IIFEs, although it's ugly and has (extremely) minor performance implications:

```
const myData = {
    myComment: ((): Comment => ({
        author: 'Steve',
        // Error! 'message' is missing
    }))(),
};
```